# Чтение и запись в файл

Tags: файлы, c++

Доброго времени суток
Есть файл "1.txt", в нем находится

```
111122223333
```

Далее запускаем программу

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream f("1.txt",ios::in|ios::out);
    f<<4444;    //заменяем 1111 на 4444
    char s[5];
    f.getline(s,5);  //затем читаем 2222
}
```

На выходе в файле получается

```
4444НННН3333
```

Т.е. единицы нормально заменились, но двойки после них не читаются, более того, почему-то перезаписываются буквами 'H'. Как сделать, чтобы программа работала корректно?
Заранее благодарен

Comment: А вы не перепутали `123.txt` и `1.txt`?

Comment: Нет, это я здесь неправильно написал. Файл "1.txt"

Comment: @Waylander, что-то Вы явно путаете. Я добавил вывод `s[]` в Вашу программу и попробовал


    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ cat 1.txt 
    444422223333
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ tttx.cpp
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
    s=2222
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ cat 1.txt 
    444422223333
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ 
    
вот видите, файл не изменился (а 2-ки вывелись).

Comment: У меня на Visual Studio 2008 почему-то результат получается не такой, как нужно. Видимо, здесь еще различия в компиляторах играют роль

Comment: Все таки в компиляторах дело. Проверил на devcpp, в файле результат тот же, но s пустая и после ввода устанавливаются флаги eof и fail

Comment: @Waylander123, не знаю, что Вы дальше делаете с `s`, а я, признаюсь, для целей печати там чуть изменил код:

    char s[6];  s[5] = 0;
    f.getline(s,5);  //затем читаем 2222
    cout << "s=" << s << '\n';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема воспроизвелась на Visual Studio 2012. Вот решение, хотя я и не знаю тонкостей работы потоков, и не могу в точности объяснить, почему такое происходит (хотел бы услышать от знатоков C++): правильно ли поступает компилятор?

Для начала, решение:

```
std::fstream f("1.txt",fstream::in|fstream::out);
f<<4444<<flush;  //заменяем 1111 на 4444
                 //и сбрасываем буфер
char s[5];
f.getline(s,5);  //затем читаем 2222
```

Дело в том, что буфера чтения и записи рассинхронизованы. При попытке записи чтение, судя по всему, «жалуется» на то, что синхронизация не произведена, а значит, будут получены неверные данные.

Автоматической синхронизации не происходит, наверное, по обычному для C++ принципу «вы не платите за то, чего не просили».

Comment: Ну учитывая ответ @avp, рассинхронизация тут вроде непричём. Может попробовать добавить режим fstream::binary при открытии? Или (если ещё мутят ситуацию кодировки) выводить не целое 4444, а текст "4444"? (виндов и vs у меня нет, так что проверить не могу)

Comment: @alexlz: Не, я трассировал, binary и кодировки в игру не вступают. Вывод строки вместо числа проблему тоже не меняет. (Если я не ошибаюсь, binary включает/выключает платформо-специфическую трансляцию концов строк.)

Comment: @VladD Programmer, beware of VS?

Comment: @alexlz: Может и так, но уже к VS 2010 Microsoft довольно хорошо вычистила имплементацию, и почти полностью соответствовала предыдущему стандарту. Так что мне кажется, маловероятно, я бы поставил на то, что имплементация в gcc более добра к отсутствию строго говоря необходимого `std::flush`.